Evaluate maximum and minimum of $Trace$ $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma^{-1/2} \rho \sigma^{-1/2} + sI}$
My problem that is "Evaluate maximum and minimum of $Trace$ $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma^{-1/2} \rho \sigma^{-1/2} + sI}$ ", in which $\sigma,\rho$ be density matrices and $s \in (0;+\infty)$.
My attempt:
Maximum: $Trace$ $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma^{-1/2} \rho \sigma^{-1/2} + sI}$ = $Trace$ $[(\sigma \rho^{-1} \sigma):(s^{-1} \sigma)]$ by Parallel sum. Then use majorization, we have
$$ Trace [(\sigma \rho^{-1} \sigma):(s^{-1} \sigma)] \le Trace [\lambda^{\downarrow}(\sigma \rho^{-1} \sigma) : s^{-1} \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma)] = Trace [\lambda^{\downarrow}(\sigma^2 \rho^{-1}) : s^{-1} \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma)]$$
$$= Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow}(\sigma^2 \rho^{-1})^{-1} : s \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma)^{-1}} = Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\uparrow}(\sigma^{-2} \rho) : s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)} = Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow}(\sigma^{-2} \rho) : s \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma)}$$
Otherwise, we have $\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) \prec \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2}) \circ \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) \Rightarrow \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) + s \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1}) \prec \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2}) \circ \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) + s \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1})$
By inequality III.13 on "Matrix Analysis - Rajendra Bhatia" and choose function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ which is a positive function on $(0,+\infty)$, it follows from inequality III.13 that
$$\dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) + s \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1})} \prec \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2}) \circ \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) + s \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1})}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) + s \lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1})} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2}) \lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\rho) + s \lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1})}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma^2 \rho^{-1})^{-1} + s \lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma)^{-1}} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma)^{-2} \lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\rho) + s \lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma)^{-1}}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^2 \rho^{-1})^{-1} + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)^{-1}} \le Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)^{-2} \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)^{-1}}$$
Since trace function is a positive function on $(0,+\infty)$ then
$$Trace [\lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^2) \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho)^{-1} : s^{-1} \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)] \le Trace [\lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^2) \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho)^{-1}] : Trace [s^{-1} \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)]$$.
We conclude that $Trace [\lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^2) \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho)^{-1}] : Trace [s^{-1} \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)]$ is the maximum of $Trace$ $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma^{-1/2} \rho \sigma^{-1/2} + sI}$.
Minimum: $Trace$ $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma^{-1/2} \rho \sigma^{-1/2} + sI}$ = $Trace$ $[(\sigma \rho^{-1} \sigma):(s^{-1} \sigma)]$. We have
$$Trace [(\sigma \rho^{-1} \sigma):(s^{-1} \sigma)] \ge Trace [\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma \rho^{-1} \sigma) : s^{-1} \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)] = Trace [\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^2 \rho^{-1}) : s^{-1} \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)]$$
$$= Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^2 \rho^{-1})^{-1} + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma)^{-1}} = Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})}$$
otherwise, we have
$$\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) \succ \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) \circ \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-2})$$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1}) \succ \lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) \circ \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-2}) + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})$$
By inequality III.13 on "Matrix Analysis - Rajendra Bhatia" and choose function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ which is a positive function with $x \in (0,+\infty)$, it follows from inequality III.13 that
$$\dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})} \succ \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) \circ \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-2}) + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho) + s \lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})} \ge \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\rho) \lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-2}) + s \lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho^{-1})^{-1} + s \lambda_i^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})} \ge \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\rho) \lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma)^{-2} + s \lambda_i^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1})}$$
Hence $Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-2} \rho^{-1})^{-1} + s \lambda^{\uparrow} (\sigma^{-1})} \ge Trace \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow} (\rho) \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma)^{-2} + s \lambda^{\downarrow} (\sigma^{-1})}$.
**

My question: Does my computation correct? Is there any inequality can
help me to transform the minimum to the same form like the maximum (parallel sum)?
Thank all!

**
